# Does MapKit in iOS supports WMS(Web Map Service), WFS(Web Feature Service) and GeoJSON Geometry

Tags: ios, dictionary, web, mapkit, geojson

I am building an iOS application and it requires the following features

I am using MapKit. Does it support the following functionalities or should we go for the third party SDKs?

**WMS(Web Map Service)
 WFS(Web Feature Service) 
 GeoJSON Geometry  support.**

When I search I found that for WMS and WFS ArcGIS Runtime SDK for iOS is available. 
https://developers.arcgis.com/ios/10-2/swift/guide/wms-layer.htm

and for GeoJSON Geometry support GEOSwift is available.
https://cocoapods.org/pods/GEOSwift

Mapbox iOS SDK is also there
https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/examples/line-geojson/

So for GeoJSON Geometry support should I go with MapBox.
and ArcGIS SDK for WMS and WFS

Thanks in advance.